# A couple of issues using Google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I have the following in a page:

```
<div id="js-recaptcha">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" style="display: inline-block;" data-sitekey="@SiteConfig.RecaptchaV2Key"></div>
</div>
```

then in script I  have:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

Now on load via jquery, I add the disabled property to the #js-recaptcha div. I can see that this has been applied. However, if I click on the form below the captcha box, it will either still tick the captcha or display a set of images. So my first question is how do I truly disable captcha?.

The second issue I have with captcha is that when the set of images are shown, when you select an image it selects the image up 1 and to the left 1 of the image selected, and this also continues when you try to press the 'verify' button, it selects a bottom image.

Comment: You are using google captcha which is third party for your application. go over google captcha API documents and find solution to disable the captcha instead of doing it using your own jquery script

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar ok...so looking at the docs, it seems like all I can do is hide. So I can live with that and it solves the first issue, but it doesn't solve the second issue and I cant see anything in the documentation to show why this might happen

Comment: that could be the desired behavior of google captcha. You can raise ticket with google captcha team and ask for the solution

Comment: I've been to the site, but cannot find where to raise a ticket. Interestingly, if I place the same code in a non-modal form for desktop the recaptcha works fine. this is on a modal form and considered for mobile